# wamp server does not start services when added "extension=php_pthreads.dll" in php.ini file

Tags: php, wamp

I have added the php7 in wamp server in windows8 32-bit. All working good, but when I am trying to use "pthreads" and follows all the steps to install "pthreads", the wamp server is not working.

I have added the line `extension=php_pthreads.dll` at the end of php.ini file of apache and trying to restart wamp server It is staring with yellow icon and not green icon as usually for successfully working. But If I removes the line `extension=php_pthreads.dll` server works properly. What might be the issue?

```
phpinfo():
Php version 7.0.3RC1 
Compiler    MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015)
and using "php_pthreads-3.1.5-7.0-ts-vc14-x86.zip" for multithreding
```

Comment: Pthreads is cli only under php7